# TeamCity ignoring SVN Revisions with new or modified external files in Pending list. However, detecting revisions with changed/new code file

Tags: svn, teamcity

Using a Subversion Repository with TeamCity Project with Externals Support set as "**Full support (load changes and checkout)**" which *Includes Externals*. Now whenever I commit a source file (.vb) it detects those revisions as Pending which is OK.
However, whenever I commit other files like (.txt, .pptx, etc.) the SVN revision for such files is not shown in the TeamCity pending list.

My questions are:

1. Let say repository revision 3000 is an abc.txt file, now can I assume while compiling 3001 version with my.vb file that this text file will be there in the build?
2. What if I want to Build Version 3002 (with a new .txt file) as this will not appear in the Pending list even if I chose to "Run" topmost revision, TeamCity chooses version 3001 only with code file.
3. Most importantly, how do I configure TeamCity to show revisions with .txt or other file as changes in Pending list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: However, whenever I commit other files like (.txt, .pptx, etc.) the SVN revision for such files is not shown in the TeamCity pending list.

***TeamCity is able to well detect pending changes, Never faced change related issues. So with gained experience at my end this is rules out. We can also build a specific revision from dashboard and use option to fetch pending changes if not shown in UI***

Q2. Let say repository revision 3000 is an abc.txt file, now can I assume while compiling 3001 version with my.vb file that this text file will be there in the build?

***Yes, during checkout file contents are not disturbed. If you're getting previous content - perform a clean build in TeamCity. You can also pass TeamCity variables to text files as a build step using msdos replace command.***

Q3. What if I want to Build Version 3002 (with a new .txt file) as this will not appear in the Pending list even if I chose to "Run" topmost revision, TeamCity chooses version 3001 only with code file.

***For that one can read 3002 from new.txt and issue a TeamCity API command to build revisions from DOS using cURL***

Q4. Most importantly, how do I configure TeamCity to show revisions with .txt or other file as changes in Pending list.

***Not required***

Answer (score 0):

Files aren't independently checked in, they are part of a commit. A commit can have as many files as you want.

When teamcity downloads the repo, it will download everything up until the revision specified, every file, changes etc.

Also teamcity doesn't check if a file has been changed, it checks to see if there is a new commit, if detected it will download the code and build it and it will do this for every commit, not every file changed.